# Generating a Jinja/YAML template for an existing resource in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I am looking forward to create a YAML template for an existing VM Instance resource in a GCP project. Is there a way to generate a Jinja Template/YAML file for an existing VM Resource in a GCP Project?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can obtain the configuration by the GCP UI. You have to enter into the VM Instance details, next scroll down and do click on [REST](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/routes) and you will be able to see the configuration as `JSON`. Then you can convert it into a YAML through this [website](https://www.json2yaml.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like there is no better solution. For example doing this for a simple VPC with a few subnetworks is already painful.